# Syntax error in PHP login page query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a PHP login page that checks weather the user entered details are in the database but it returns the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access 
>       violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
>       corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
>       'SLEECT * FROM users where username = NULL AND password = NULL' at line 1 in 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\sign\login.php:18 Stack trace: #0 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\sign\login.php(18): PDOStatement->execute() #1
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\sign\login.php(31): SignIn() #2 {main} thrown in 
>       C:\xampp\htdocs\sign\login.php on line 18

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

---

```
<?php  
include('connection.php');
$username =$_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if($username == '') {
$errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Username';
$errflag = true;
}
if($password == '') {
$errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Password';
$errflag = true;
}
function SignIn(){
global $connection;
$search = $connection->prepare("SLEECT * FROM users where username = 
:username AND password = :password");
$search->bindParam(':username',$username);
$search->bindParam(':password',$password);
$result = $search->execute();
$count = $result->rowcount();
if($count> 0)
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    echo "welcom to the page ";
}
else{
    echo "wron email or password";
}
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
SignIn();
}
?>
```

the code written in `connection.php` is

```
<?php
try{
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=signup;charset=utf8mb4', 
'root', '');
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $err){
echo $err->getMessage();
die();
}
?>
```

the HTML code written is

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="login.php">
<b>Enter your username: </b><br>
<input type="text" name="username"><br>
<b>Enter your password: </b><br>
<input type="password" name ="password"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: TYPO : SLEECT spelling is SELECT :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1ST :** `SLEECT` spelling is `SELECT`

**2ND :** Follow the dolly aswin suggested steps .

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    ......
}
```

**3RD :** `rowcount()` should be `rowCount()` . `c` should be caps.

**4TH :**   you need to get the `rowcount` from statement .not from Boolean value `$result` only contains `Boolean` value `true` or `false`

```
 $count = $result->rowCount();
```

change to

```
$count = $search->rowCount();
```

Comment: yes I have done it thankyou but it gives an another error I have even passed the variables $username and $password into the function SignIn() but I received the fallowing error   --- Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowcount() on boolean in C    can you please help me out

Comment: the entire error is ---
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowcount() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\sign\login.php:28 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sign\login.php(19): SignIn('john', 'america') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sign\login.php on line 28

Comment: @Ram use `rowCount()` instead of `rowcount()`

Comment: yeahs c should be caps

Comment: thankyou for the answer but even if the 'c' is cpital in rowCount() it return the same error in the fallowing way ---    
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\sign\login.php:28 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sign\login.php(19): SignIn('john', 'america') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sign\login.php on line 28

Comment: I think your query failing due to  some reason try to use try catch black  try { $search->execute();}
    catch(PDOException $e){echo $e->getMessage();}

Comment: change this line $count = $search->rowCount();

Comment: @JYoThI it is finally got working but can you please explain the difference when my code is -----    $result =  $search->execute();
 $count = $result->rowCount();                                                                          it did not work but when the code is     ----    $search->execute();
 $count = $search->rowCount();      it got worked may I know what is difference between both of them??

Comment: $result=$search->execute(); here $search->execute();  it will return true or false . so $result only contains true or false only . you cant fetch the rowcount form those boolean values . you need to get the rowcount from statement i.e $search . did you got it ? @Ram

Comment: @JYoThI and Dolly Aswin thankyou for the explanation and helping me solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

You get error message like this because you call variables not defined `$username` and `$password` inside `SignIn()` function. That's why, the query will treat them as `null`.

> > Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access 
> >     violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
> >     corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
> >     'SLEECT * FROM users where username = NULL AND password = NULL' at line 1 in

You can pass it on function defenition

```
function SignIn($username, $password)
```

Then please check the `$_POST["submit"]` first, then validate the `username` & `password` and call `SignIn($username, $password)`

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $errflag  = false;
    if($username == '') {
       $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Username';
       $errflag = true;
    }

    if($password == '') {
       $errmsg_arr[] = 'You must enter your Password';
       $errflag = true;
    }

    if ($errflag == false) {
       SignIn($username, $password);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the above change but previosly I have entered my username as 'john' and password as 'america' theese are also in my database but when I press login I received the fallowing error

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SLEECT * FROM users where username = 'john' AND password = 'america'' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\sign\login.php:27 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sign\login.php(27): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\sign\login.php(19): SignIn('john', 'america') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sign\login.php on line 27

Comment: and line 27 is this statement  -  $result = $search->execute();

Comment: Your sql is typo. `SLEECT * FROM users where username = NULL AND password = NULL`. This is should be `SELECT` not `SLEECT`

Comment: Edit your comment . at the end  SELECT not SELECT @DollyAswin